# add a delay at the end of a loop in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

*I would like to add a delay of 5 seconds after likeMe() loop has finished.  Once finsh I would like to trigger a click on the log out button of Facebook.*

I'm stupid when it comes to javascript symantics; therefore I have no idea on how to trigger any of this?  With this in mind where/how would I add this effect after the loops is over:

I've normally use `.promise().done()` to do the finally steps after a loops but I have no idea how to place this `$.delay(5000).promise().done( $('input[value="Log Out"]').click());` within the javascript.

BACKGROUND: creating a installation art piece using arudino, processing and & greasemonkey jQuery.

FULL SCRIPT:

```
unsafeWindow.likeMe = likeMe;
function likeMe() 
{   

        input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
        {
            myID = input[i].getAttribute("data-profileid");
            if(myID != null && myID.indexOf("342584172457437") >= 0)
                input[i].click();
        }
        $.delay(5000).promise().done( $('input[value="Log Out"]').click()); 
        // this is wrong but yeah i have no clue where or how to put it on here.

}


$(window).load(function(){

    var isCtrl = false;
    document.onkeyup=function(e) {
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
    }
    document.onkeydown=function(e){
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
        if(e.which == 46 && isCtrl == true) {
            likeMe()

            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: you have to use settimeout instead of delay

Comment: detect the end of the loop, `if(input.length == -1){ setTimeout(function(){ // code here }, 5000);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) like

```
function likeMe() 
{   

    input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
        {
            myID = input[i].getAttribute("data-profileid");
            if(myID != null && myID.indexOf("342584172457437") >= 0)
            input[i].click();
        }

   setTimeout(function() {
        $('input[value="Log Out"]').click();
   }, 5000);

}
```

or inside the `onkeydown` like

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
        if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
        if(e.which == 46 && isCtrl == true) {
            likeMe();
            setTimeout(function() {
               $('input[value="Log Out"]').click();
            }, 5000); 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But not in both at the same time.

Comment: Damn joy you got me on autofollow dont you?!  You answer all my questions!

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, Nop Sir I don't. It's coincidence maybe. :)

Comment: Anyway, it would have been the most fruitful form of stalking :]

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('input[value="Log Out"]').click();
}, 5000);
```

to execute a function in five seconds.

Comment: where would i place this winthin the loop?

Comment: You put it whenever you want to start the 5 seconds.  I would assume you put it after your `for` loop finishes executing.